# How to create Access textbox that I can just type into?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to create a textbox that a user can enter an arbitrary string into. No matter what I try, I always have to link the textbox with a query, table, or something else -- I just want to be able to type anything into a textbox. Is this possible?

Clarification: I'm using access 2003. Also, I'm talking about the user typing into it, not 'me'. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: what code are you currently using? I think we all need a little bit more information as to why this isn't currently working.

`<textarea name='text'>type text here</textarea>`

That should work fine but there has to be another issue. Also what is your code for processing the form?

Comment: this is in Access 2003. i'll be using vba to pull the text from the textbox. i don't think i need to use html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your form is data-bound, then the data source must be updatable. Otherwise it will lock the form, including controls that are not data-bound. For instance queries with GROUP BY statements or UNION queries are not updatable.

If the form is locked or disabled in some way, all controls on that form will be locked or disabled as well.

---

EDIT:

[image]

AllowEdits is a form property, not a control property.

Comment: i don't think the form is data bound (when i click properties on the form, the "control source" field is empty)

Comment: "allow edits" isn't a choice, but enabled is set to yes and locked is set to no.

Comment: there is also no "record source" property on the form

Comment: WAIT, there got it. edits was set to false on the property sheet of the form. i think it works now. ty HansUp

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of Access that you are using but every version that i have used up to Access 2007 has a unbound texbox. Try going into design mode on your form. In your title bar you should see something like this that will allow you to enter a textox on your form.

[image]

Once you drag that onto your form you should be able to type anything you want into it. Is that what you were asking or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: i'm using 2003. the textbox is unbound -- i didn't change anything after creating it. locked=no, enabled=yes, all i did was give it a name... i'm not sure what's preventing me from typing into it.

Comment: Are you able to mouse (or tab) into the textbox?

Comment: yes. when i am using the form (not designing), i can see/select the default text, but can't delete or type anything.

Comment: when the form is running what do you see in the textbox? anything?

Answer (score -1):

When you create a text box it will say unbound. Leave it saying unbound.